# What does systemd "thawing" mean?

Tags: systemd

From `systemctl status foo`. I have both a `foo.service` and a `foo.timer`:

```
Active: activating (auto-restart) (thawing) since Fri 2020-10-09 21:32:56 UTC; 3min 1s ago
```

I can't find the word "thaw" anywhere in the docs. This is systemd 246.6.

Comment: Really? I found it with one web search. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#thaw%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6

Comment: I had looked in the man pages of the unit files, not systemctl itself, and man -k. But I still don't know what it means if something is "thawing" for a long time.

Comment: It means you have some kind of problem. That ought to be more-or-less immediate. Anything interesting in the journal?

Answer (score 3):

It means the same thing that is in your description i.e.activating. Thaw is needed to unfreeze a unit. Freeze means suspending all the process contained in a cgroup corresponding to a unit. This is usually done to save resource. So whenever we want the unit back, it is thawed. systemd has control over units so it handles freeze and thaw depending on task. Although a user can manually also issue freeze on a unit and then thaw it.

```
systemctl freeze [pattern]
```

and then

```
systemctl thaw [pattern]
```

Check `journalctl` for the debug logs.
Quick tip : Don't run on a unit that is running your system.